# Bounding the difference between $H_N$ and $\log N$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

we consider the relation given: $$\int_n^{n+1}\frac{1}{x}dx < \frac{1}{n} < \int_n^{n+1}\frac{1}{x-1}dx$$

For $n>1$. We are to show $$\lim_{N\to\infty}\left[\left(\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{n}\right) - \ln(N)\right]$$ is finite and to find the upper and lower bounds. My attempt is as follows. We note from the above inequality.: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}<\int_2^\infty\frac{1}{x-1}dx +1$$  Follows from here $$\lim_{N\to\infty}\left[\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n} - \ln(N)\right]<\lim_{N\to\infty}\left[\int_2^N\frac{1}{x-1}dx +1 - \ln(N)\right]$$ Which gives the upper bound as $1$. Similar logic for the lower bound gave the final result as $$0<\lim_{N\to\infty}\left[\left(\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{n}\right) - \ln(N)\right]<1$$ Is this approach correct? Is it possible to have a tighter bound using the same approach? Many thanks

Comment: How are you getting your upper bound of one? I believe the upper limit of integration should be $N+1$.

Comment: The integral goes to $\ln{(N-1)} - \ln{1} - \ln(N) + 1$ which in the limit gives just 1 by itself as $\ln{N-1}$ and $\ln{N}$ subtract to $0$?

Comment: Ah OK. Your reasoning seems fine. Except for your limit of integration.

Comment: @Tim is correct about the upper limit of integration: you have $\frac1n<\int_n^{n+1}\frac{dx}{1-x}$, so you want $N+1$ as your upper limit of integration when computing the upper bound. Otherwise it looks fine, and I don’t think that you can get better bounds this way.

Comment: Ah yes! I see! Many thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument correctly proves that
$$ S=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\right) \tag{1}$$
converges to some constant in $(0,1)$. It is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) $\gamma$:
$$ \gamma = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{1-e^{-x}}-\frac{1}{x}\right)e^{-x}\,dx = 0.5772156649\ldots\tag{2}$$
Notice that, from:
$$ H_N-\log(N+1) = \sum_{n=1}^{N}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\right) = \gamma-\sum_{n>N}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)\tag{3}$$
and from:
$$ \frac{1}{2n(n+1)}\leq\frac{1}{n}-\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right) \leq \frac{1}{2n(n-1)},\tag{4} $$
that follows from the convexity of the function $g(t)=\frac{1}{t}$, we have:
$$ H_N = \log(N+1)+\gamma-\frac{1}{2N+\theta}, \qquad \theta\in[0,2],\tag{5}$$
that is way stronger than the initial bound. It is also possible to improve $(5)$ up to $\theta\in\left[\frac{16}{10},\frac{17}{10}\right]$, or up to:

> $$ H_N = \log N + \gamma + \frac{1}{2N+\theta},\qquad \theta\in\left[\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{5}\right].\tag{6}$$

Comment: You can even obtain a complete asymptotic expansion in negative powers of $N$.

Comment: Interesting. Many thanks for this!